# Extract ID using preg_match not working

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to use preg_math to extract an ID number from some content like this...

```
$content = "[gravityform id="837" name="Test Form" title="false" description="false"]";
preg_match('/[gravityform\s*id="\s*([0-9]+)/i', $content, $id);
echo $id[1];
```

This isn't working for me though and is returning an error..

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses
```

Where am I going wrong and is preg_match the best way of doing this?

Comment: `[` is a special character in regular expressions for a character class such as `[a-z]`. Escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quote in $content to avoid compilation error and escape the `[` in the start of your regular expression:

```
$content = '[gravityform id="837" name="Test Form" title="false" description="false"]';
preg_match('/\[gravityform\s*id="\s*([0-9]+)/i', $content, $id);
echo $id[1];
```

Output:

```
837
```